# restoring Division in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to write a program in MIPS assembly language that implements the restoring division algorithm.

I found very good example of my task that I have to do, the thread is old and closed, and I don't fully understand it.

```
http://forums.extremeoverclocking.com/showthread.php?p=2693342
```

I have few questions:

1. so in the end how should look like good code?
   Beacuse i understand that the code in 1st post is wrong ?
2. What is good algorithm of restoring Division?

   " 
   You are dividing two numbers: a/b = c, remainder = d

   Register A = a
   Register B = b
   Register P = a "connected" set of two registers (64 bit register)

   1. Shift the double regiaster (P,A) one bit left

      - use zero sign extension for unsigned values
      - force MSB(P) to fall off the upper end
   2. Subtract b from P
   3. If the result is < 0
      LSB(A) = 0
      else LSB(A) = 1
   4. If result is negative
      P = P + b

   Repeat n times (for n-bit values)
   Contents of register A = a/b 
   Contents of register P = remainder(a/b)"

is this good algorithm? can someone write it in much simplier english? Cause i don;t understand it.

addition:

code from 1-st post:

```
.data
    GETA:           .asciiz "Enter A "
    GETB:           .asciiz "Enter B "
    QMSG:           .asciiz "Q = "
    RMSG:           .asciiz "R = "
    NL:             .asciiz "\n"
    ERR:            .asciiz "Divide by zero error\n"
    left:           .word 1
    right:          .word 1
.text
.globl main
main:
    # Prompt for an integer A: divisor
    li $v0, 4                            
    la $a0, GETA                           
    syscall                                     
    # Read A from user
    li $v0, 5                              
    syscall                              

    move $t0, $v0                         
    # Prompt for an integer B: dividend
    li $v0, 4                             
    la $a0, GETB                         
    syscall     

    # Read B from user
    li $v0, 5                               
    syscall                               
    move $a1, $v0                          

# Initialize quotient register to zero
# Initialize left half of Divisor regisiter with divisor
# Initialize remainder register with the dividend (right aligned)
# 1. Remainder = Remainder - Divisor
#    Remainder >= 0 goto Step 2a.
#    Remainder < 0 goto Step 2b.
# 2a. Shift quotient register to the left, setting rightmost bit to 1
# 2b. Restore the original value bu Remainder = Remainder + Divisor
#     Shift quotient register to the left setting new LSB to zero
# 3. Shift divisor register to the right 1 bit
# < 33 repitions, goto step 1
# >= 33 repititions, print result 
#
# Register usage:
# $a0 = divisor
# $a1 = dividend
# $a2 = quotient
# $a3 = remainder
# $t4 = counter of 33 repetitions
# $t0 = divisor (temp)
initialize:
    li $a2, 0                               # $a2 = quotient = 0
    swl $t0, left
    lwl $a0, left                           # $a0 = left half of divisor
    swr $a1, right
    lwr $a3, right                          # $a3 = remainder = $a2
    li $t4, 33                              # $t4 = counter = 33

step_one:
    sub $a3, $a3, $a0
    bge $a3, $zero, step_two_a
    blt $a3, $zero, step_two_b

step_two_a:
    #slt $a2, $zero, $a2
    sll $a2, $a2, 1
    ori $a2, $a2, 1
    j step_three

step_two_b:

    add $a3, $a3, $a0
    sll $a2, $a2, 1

step_three:

    sra $a0, $a0, 1

step_four:

    addi $t4, $t4, -1
    bge $t4, $zero, step_one
    beq $t4, $zero, print_result

print_result:

    li $v0, 4                  
    la $a0, QMSG                     
    syscall                   

    move $a0, $a2                      
    li $v0, 1                         
    syscall                            

    li $v0, 4                          
    la $a0, NL                         
    syscall                           

    li $v0, 4                    
    la $a0, RMSG                     
    syscall                     

    move $a0, $a3                      
    li $v0, 1                          
    syscall                            

    li $v0, 4                          
    la $a0, NL                         
    syscall

    j exit_program                    

exit_program:
    li $v0, 10                       
    syscall
```

probably missing something like

Code:

```
 # shift the double register (P,A) one bit left
    slt $t2, $v0, $zero                  # store MSB of hi
    sll $v0, $v0, 1                      # shift hi left 1 bit
    slt $t3, $v1, $zero                  # store MSB of lo
    or $v0, $v0, $t2                     # move MSB of lo into LSB of hi
    sll $v1, $v1, 1                      # shift lo left 1 bit
```

how should like fine code??

Comment: Please don't just link to something and expect us to know what you want. Links can become invalid over time. Please explain what you are trying to accomplish in the post body, in addition to the link you provided.

Comment: well this is way i ask first and second question. I want to know answer to them according to the link. In addition i added code

Comment: A question on this site should be as self contained as possible. Imagine if the link becomes invalid. In that case the question as it stands has no context. A good question should have a clear context even if things it links to are not available.

Comment: I made my own modification. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: yes you have, could you help me ?

Comment: I am only trying to make your post more understandable to those who might be able to help. I unfortunately have no experience or expertise in MIPS assembly language.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the corrected code for restoring division with dvide by zero error handling:**

```
.data
    GETA:           .asciiz "Enter Dividend: "
    GETB:           .asciiz "Enter Divisor: "
    QMSG:           .asciiz "Quotient = "
    RMSG:           .asciiz "Reminder = "
    NL:             .asciiz "\n"
    ERR:            .asciiz "Divide by zero error\n"
    left:           .word 1
    right:          .word 1
.text
.globl main

# Register usage:
# $a1 = Divisor
# $a2 = Quotient(Q)
# $a3 = Reminder
# $t4 = No. of bits = 31
# $s0 = A

main:

# Prompt for an integer A: dividend
    li $v0, 4                            
    la $a0, GETA                          
    syscall
                                       
# Read A from user
    li $v0, 5                              
    syscall                              

    move $a2, $v0                  
                   
# Prompt for an integer B: divisor
    li $v0, 4                            
    la $a0, GETB                        
    syscall    

# Read B from user
    li $v0, 5                              
    syscall                              
    move $a1, $v0                                        

#initialize:
    li $t4, 30                  # $t4 = counter = 30 = no of loops
    addi $s0, $s0, 0            # A=0

# Exception handling:
    beq $a1,$zero,zeroerror     #Raises an exception when a/0 is encountered
   
#step1: To shift Q and A
loop:
    andi $t5, $a2, 1073741824   # extracting the msb-1 of divident(quotient)
    srl $t5, $t5, 30            # move msb-1 to right
    sll $a2, $a2, 1             # shift Q by 1 position
    andi $a2, $a2, 2147483647   # to neglect 32nd po
    sll $s0, $s0, 1             # shift A by 1 position
    or $s0, $s0, $t5            # add the msb of Q to A
   
#step2: A = A - M
    addi $s5, $s0, 0            # storing A
    sub $s0, $s0, $a1           # A=A-M
   
#step3: Compare the msb of A to obtain lsb of Q
    andi $t5, $s0, 2147483648   # get the msb of A
    beq $t5, $zero, cond1       # if A[msb] = 0, jump to cond1
    j cond2                     # if A[msb] = 1, jump to cond2

#cond1
cond1:  ori $a2, $a2, 1         # if a[msb] = 0, q[lsb]=1
    j condover

#cond2
cond2: andi $a2, $a2, 4294967294# if A[msb] = 1, q[lsb]=0
    addi $s0, $s5, 0            # restoring A
    j condover

condover:
    addi $t4, $t4, -1           # n =n-1
    bge $t4, $zero, loop        # loop for n times
   

print_result:

    li $v0, 4                  
    la $a0, QMSG                    
    syscall                  

    move $a0, $a2                      
    li $v0, 1                        
    syscall                            

    li $v0, 4                          
    la $a0, NL                        
    syscall                          

    li $v0, 4                    
    la $a0, RMSG                    
    syscall                    

    move $a0, $s0                      
    li $v0, 1                          
    syscall                            

    li $v0, 4                          
    la $a0, NL                        
    syscall

    j exit_program                    

exit_program:
    li $v0, 10                      
    syscall
zeroerror:
# Show the Error on console
    li $v0, 4                            
    la $a0, ERR                          
    syscall
    j exit_program
```

Check out this video for more info on debugging: [Debug MIPS code Efficiently](https://youtu.be/-zn6n8NZ6l4)

Check out this video for detailed explanation of the algorithm : [Restoring division algorithm explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzV6gYpVLuc)